# Liberação da gridi do datagridviewr no botão alterar

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Bom dia, tenho uma duvida, tenho um datagridviwer, que desmarquei a opção de alteração do campos, e preciso fazer que quando o usuário clicar no botão alterar eu libere a grid para alteração, como posso fazer isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "_desmarquei a opção de alteração do campos_" Como você fez isso?

Comment: Coloquei a imagem pra mostrar, agora preciso habilitar a edição quando clikar no botão alterar.

Comment: Pronto, veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa *flag* apenas marca o elemento como `ReadOnly`, para desfazer isso em tempo de execução é mudar este valor.

Por exemplo:

```
private static void btLiberarBloquearGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.ReadOnly = !dataGridView.ReadOnly;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito muito obrigado era isso mesmo que eu precisava Vlw